# MongoCollection group question

Tags: php, mongodb

```
<?php

$collection->insert(array("category" => "fruit", "name" => "apple"));
$collection->insert(array("category" => "fruit", "name" => "peach"));
$collection->insert(array("category" => "fruit", "name" => "banana"));
$collection->insert(array("category" => "veggie", "name" => "corn"));
$collection->insert(array("category" => "veggie", "name" => "broccoli"));

$keys = array("category" => 1);

$initial = array("items" => array());

$reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.items.push(obj.name); }";

$g = $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);

echo json_encode($g['retval']);

?>
```

not clear line `$keys = array("category" => 1);` why need write "category" => 1 instead of symply write "category" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why need write `"category" => 1` instead of symply write `"category"` ?

The query engine for MongoDB used JSON objects. So everything is a key-value pair. The PHP driver is representing key-value pairs using hash tables (*or dictionaries*).

If you look at the [aggregation documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group), it has the following example:

```
key: { a:true, b:true }
```

In PHP this would be represented as

```
$key: array('a' => 1, 'b' => 1)
```

I agree that the `1` seems unnecessary, but it's there to keep the JSON syntax valid.